# PopupWindow.showAtLocation() causes WindowManager$BadTokenException when using onSaveInstanceState() to handle device rotation

Tags: android, popupwindow, screen-rotation

I have been working on a straight-forward file manager application. Devices that I have been using for testing are LG Nexus 4 (v4.3) and Xperia x10i (v2.3.7). The performance on x10i, although a bit sluggish, has been problem-free.

**On rotation:**

There are several `PopupWindows` that I keep track of. I use flags to determine which `PopupWindow` is currently on screen (presently, at most one PopupWindow is on screen at any given time). In `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle),` I save these flags using the `Bundle`. In `onCreate(Bundle)`, I retrieve these flags and use them in `onPostExecute()` of an `AsyncTask(called in onResume() and used for populating the ListView with data)`.

**The problem:**

If a `PopupWindow` is showing when the device is rotated, the activity is destroyed, recreated, and the `PopupWindow` is displayed again. This works well on both the devices. But, today, I rotated `x10i` from `90` degrees to `270` degrees while the search popup was showing. The app crashed because of the following exception:

```
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:544)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:907)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:767)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at com.apprehension.phylerfilemanager.Phyler.showPopupSearch(Phyler.java:2852)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at com.apprehension.phylerfilemanager.Phyler$DisplayFilesTask.onPostExecute(Phyler.java:3453)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at com.apprehension.phylerfilemanager.Phyler$DisplayFilesTask.onPostExecute(Phyler.java:1)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
08-08 01:55:51.961: E/AndroidRuntime(32373):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 2852:

```
popupWindowSearch.showAtLocation(popupViewSearch, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

If I rotate and pause on every 90 degrees, the problem is not there. The crash happens when the device undergoes 180 degree rotation without a pause.

**Saving the flags:**

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);            

    if (searchPopup) {
        outState.putBoolean("searchPopup", searchPopup);
        outState.putString("searchKeyword", searchKeyword);
        outState.putInt("searchType", searchType);          
    }

    if (....) {
        ........
        ........
    }
}
```

**Retrieving the flags in `onCreate(Bundle)`:**

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {

    rotated = true;

    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("searchPopup")) {
        searchPopup = true;
        searchKeyword = savedInstanceState.getString("searchKeyword");
        searchType = savedInstanceState.getInt("searchType");
    }

    ....
    ....
}
```

An `AsyncTask` is executed from `onResume()`. In `onPostExecute()` of this `AsyncTask`:

```
if (rotated) {
    rotated = false;
    if (searchPopup) {
        showPopupSearch(searchType, searchKeyword);     // Line 3453                        
    }
    ....
    ....
} else {
    searchPopup = false;
    ....
    ....
}
```

The exception is not thrown while testing on Nexus 4. I have also tried posting a `Runnable` to `mContentView's (the activity's main view)` message queue. The problem persists.

I think there is a problem in the way I am handling screen rotation. In apps that I have used, the screen rotation and layout changes happen smoothly. In my app's case, you can literally tell that the `PopupWindow` is being dismissed and recreated. Do most apps handle screen rotation using `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`? I have read that this approach isn't correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is most likely happening is that the x10i is doing two `Activity` instantiations. This is causing two `AsyncTasks` to run. The first one will end up having a reference to an instance of an `Activity` that, in the eyes of the framework and the window manager, no longer exists (or should exist), causing a null token and the resulting exception.

In your `Activity#onStop` you should probably set `AsyncTask#cancel` and in `AsyncTask#onPostExecute` check if its canceled and if so don't create the popup window.

---

Actual solution:

Create a flag in the `Activity` that is set to false in `onCreate()`. In `onStop()` set it to true and then in `onPostExecute` check if it is set and if so do not show the popup window.

Comment: I was so optimistic about your suggestion. And yes, rightly so. Cancelling the `AsyncTask` in `onDestroy()` and adding a check before showing the PopupWindow: `if (!displayFilesTask.isCancelled()) { ...showAtLocation(...); }` does make the crashing less frequent: about 1 in 5 rotations. Do you think one can assume that the user isn't a juggler?

Comment: Try onStop(). That's called when the Activity is no longer visible and won't have a window handle. onDestory() is called during clean up and it may be waiting to do cleanup after all the orientation changes are finished.

Comment: I tried cancelling the `AsyncTask` in onStop(). Similar result. Then, I created a boolean `cancelAll` and set it to `false` in `onCreate()` and to `true` in `onStop()`. Instead of cancelling the `AsyncTask`, I performed a check against `cancelAll` before showing the `PopupWindow`. This has completely fixed the problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Could you please append an edit to your answer, summing up this comment?

Comment: It's interesting that the flag worked but setting cancel didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Showing PopupWindow as

```
final View parent = findViewById(R.id.{parentId});
parent.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mPopup.showAtLocation(parent, ...);
    }
});
```

has solved the issue.